# Javascript: Why doesn't "if( element != '' || element != null)" work?

Tags: javascript

I have this piece of code in my script

```
var therow;
var rowtitle = ['Name', 'Weight'];
for(var i=0;i<7;i++) {
    therow = prompt(rowtitle[i]);
    if(therow != '' || therow != null) {
           //some code
    } else {
          //more code
    }
therow = null;
}
```

The loop works fine, the prompt works too. The problem is

```
if(therow != '' || therow != null)
```

I know this because I have tried

```
if(therow != '')
```

And

```
if(therow != null)
```

...independently, and they behave as expected.

Why is it that when I combine the above two in a single if statement it does nothing?

Is there something wrong with the above code?

Comment: Can you reproduce it in a fiddle so we can have a look ?

Comment: You could use `if(!therow)`

Comment: have you tried `console.log(therow)` ?

Comment: You probably mean `&&` and not `||`

Comment: because `0 == "" == undefined == null == NaN == false` use `===`

Comment: This will always return `true`.

Comment: Check answer here, maybe it's your key to success:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45009210/6434747

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it will always be true.

You've said `if it's not a blank string OR it's not NULL`. When it's NULL, it's not a blank string (so its true). When it's a blank string, it's not NULL (so it's true).

What you want is `if (therow != '' && therow != null)` or more likely `if (therow)`. I've also seen `if (!!therow)`, which forces it into an actual bolean value.

Comment: Technically, it will be false if therow is undefined

Comment: @SimonBelanger therow is actually defined.

Comment: @DavidHeisnam You are right. `prompt` never returns `undefined`. My apologies.

Comment: I found this particular problem difficult to grasp. But I get it now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

I would use an &&. You want it to not be null AND not be empty right?

Comment: but that will still not work, because we have no clue qwhats in therow. And thats not what he is asking, and this is not an answer.

Comment: Actually, I want it to not be null OR not be empty.

Answer (score 1):

try use this:

```
if (!!therow){
           //some code
    } else {
          //more code
    }
```

it's shorter way

Answer (score 0):

Use [DeMorgans theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) to convert `therow != '' || therow != null` to `therow == '' && therow == null` And study the transformation. How can `therow` be `''` and `null` at the same time?

Comment: For the last question, that's why I used OR.