# Detect empty value on prompt

Tags: javascript, prompt

How to detect an empty value when user presses ok on prompt (and previously empties the prompt field)? I need to overwrite the old value with the new (empty) value. I'm doing this:

```
var oldVal = 'something';
var newVal = prompt("Enter new value:", oldVal);
```

Currently it returns null if user empties value and clicks ok.

But at the same time I need to check for null value because if user clicks 'cancel', it will return null, which I don't want as new value.

Comment: `prompt` does not return NULL when the input is empty and OK is pressed; it returns the empty string.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It does not return `null` if the user hits OK - it will return an empty string.  You are probably not testing the return value properly.  If you want to test between the three different return states, you can do that like this:

```
var oldVal = 'something';
var newVal = prompt("Enter new value:", oldVal);
if (newVal === "") {
    // user pressed OK, but the input field was empty
} else if (newVal) {
    // user typed something and hit OK
} else {
    // user hit cancel
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Kx2EK/

---

Your comment suggests that you're using this code to test the result:

```
if(!newVal || oldVal == newVal)return false;
```

When the user clears the field and presses OK, newVal will be `""` (an empty string).  `!newVal` will be `true` so you will return `false`.  An empty string is a falsey value just like `null`.  You need to more explicitly check for `null` like this:

```
if (newVal === null || newVal === oldVal) {
    // cancel button was hit
    // or the same value was entered
    return false;
}
```

Working demo of this logic: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/ynwBx/

Note: I'm using `===` to prevent the javascript interpreter from doing any type casting as I want to only explicitly check for `null`.

Comment: But I need to have this in my statement:  if(!newVal || oldVal == newVal)return false; so I need to check for null. And if the user empties prompt field, then presses ok, null will be returned.

Comment: @Toniq - you don't seem to understand that `!newVal` will also match an empty string so you aren't distinguishing between the `null` (cancel button) and an empty string (ok button).  I've added code to my answer that will show you how to do what you asked.

Comment: @DomVinyard - What exactly doesn't work?  What do you see on what button and what value of the field in which demo?

Answer (score 3):

A Bit old, but it may be worthwhile to simply include a test for the string's length in the same if() statement

```
if(newVal !=null & newVal.length>0){
```

Check both for Cancel and an empty entry.

Comment: Have you tested this? There should be `&&`, not binary `&` (although I'm not sure if `&` will work here as well)

Answer (score 2):

In most browsers prompt will return `null` if user presses cancel, but in some (Safari, for ex.) it returns empty string. If user enters some text and presses ok, prompt will return entered text, if user pressed ok without entering text, it will return empty string.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>    
<p>Click the button to demonstrate the prompt box.</p>    
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>    
<p id="demo"></p>    
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var answer=prompt('Reason for deletion?');
    var n = answer.length;
    if(n > 5)
    {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
    "Hello " + answer + "! How are you today?";
    }
    else if(n == 0)
    {  
    myFunction()
    } 
}
</script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide explanation as well

Comment: You can check null value in prompt box... if the the prompt box return a null , then it return to the same function...

Answer (score 0):

I have see other comment that seem like solved your problem, but I think it might can no t be the best answer or solution here is your code

```
if (newVal == "") {
//action
}
```

it might seem work, but it might probably cause a problem or a little bug, is that the user can just type two blank or white-space to bypass your code, here is my solution

```
If (newVal.trim() == "") {
 //action
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When user hits OK without entering any value, it returns NaN and you can check it by isNaN() function.

Answer (score 0):

```
// this is TRUE, when user presses Cancel / ESC
window.prompt('Type whatever', '') === null

// this is TRUE, when presses Enter and value is empty
// note that it will be FALSE if canceled or if "0" is entered
window.prompt('Type whatever', '') == ''
```

Try here:
https://jsfiddle.net/L5zrdeq9/

Answer (score -1):

Simple to see if both cancel or ok with empty string

```
function valueIsSet(value)
{
    return (value && value !== "")
}

// example:

var name;
while (!valueIsSet(name) {
    name = prompt("Please enter your name");
}

alert("Welcome " + name);
```