# JavaScript - Lookup element in array and handle nulls from user prompt

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript and I'm doing this color guessing game as an assignment. My script is below. I've tried many different ways that I can think of and I just couldn't make it work.

In summary I have two problems.

1. How can I check if a value that is typed in by a user exists in the array?
2. If a user clicks Ok with no value, how can I make sure to exclude null values?enter code here

Script is Below. If you run the program it will show the answer that is to be guessed by the user (only for testing).If the user guess is correct then the page color will be that color. Any help will be much appreciated.

```
<DOCTYPE! HTML>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Color Guessing Game</TITLE>

   </HEAD>

     <body onload="do_game()">

      <script type="text/javascript">

       var target;
       var target_index;
       var guess_input;
       var finished = false;
        var guess_input_text;
       var guesses = 0
        var color= ["Blue","Coral","Cyan","Fuchsia","Gold","Lavender","Lime","Red","Tan"];
         var myBody=document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
         var check_color = colors.indexOf(guess_input);

        function do_game(){
        var random_number_integer = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() *  colors.length-1)];
        target = random_number_integer;
         alert(target);

        while (!finished) {

         guess_input_text = prompt("I am thinking of one these colors: \n\n\n" + 
                                colors.toString() + 
                              "\n\n\n What color am I thinkning of?");

    guess_input = guess_input_text;
    guesses += 1;
    finsihed = check_guess(); 
    }
}
  function check_guess() {

       if (guess_input == null){
         alert("Type in a color.");
          return false;
}

if (guess_input > target){
    alert("Your input is alphabetically lower than mine!" +
            "\n\nPlease Try Again.\n\n");
        return false;
}
if (guess_input < target){
    alert("Your input is alphabetically higher than mine!" +
            "\n\nPlease Try Again.\n\n");
    return false;
}

alert("Yes!!!, the correct color was: " + target +
        "\n\n\n The Number of guesses:" + guesses +
        "\n\n\nGood Job\n\n\n");
myBody.style.background=guess_input;
return true;

 }

 </script>
 </body>
 </HTML>
```

Comment: pay attention colors !== color then to find in array A a string S you can use S.match(new RegExp(A.join('|')));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer 1 : Use indexOf : [(Docs)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Answer 2: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20533178/3603806

Answer (score 0):

```js
// check whether the array or string empty
function is_empty(obj){
 if (obj == null || (obj == '' && obj.length == 0)){
  return true;
 }
 else {
  return false;
 }
}


// check whether this elem is included in arr
function is_included(elem, arr){
    if (is_empty(arr) || is_empty(elem) || arr.toString().indexOf(elem) == -1){
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: fails with non empty array `is_empty([""])`

Comment: @fedeghe, thanks for figuring it out. answer updated. thanks